# Enumerate the results on a table

Tags: sql, while-loop, do-while

As example we have 3 different Quantity Input
a=5 b=6 c=15
then on the query we have as total result 50 rows
the necessity is to enumerate the  rows as **a** starting from value 1.
then the sixth one start again in 1 but with **b** value
and repeat with c, if the input is over then put null

--SQL server 2014 Management Studio

[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CfIpH.jpg)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CfIpH.jpg)

Comment: Please, post sample data and desired output in text format along with your current code and description of what is the issue with it. Stack Overflow is not a codewriting service

Comment: Why enumerate anything? SQL is a set-based language. If you want to calculate row numbers you can use eg `ROW_NUMBER` or another ranking function. You didn't post any examples or queries so it's hard to guess what you want and propose solutions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is kind of *questionable* because rows in a table in a relational database aren't stored in any particular order, so - without any column which would determine that order, you're either out of luck or you have to rely on database's features which will help you sort rows, somehow.

You didn't specify the database you use; this is Oracle example. See if you can adjust it to database you use.

The idea is: three loops, one for each of variables (`a`, `b`, `c`). Cursor `FOR` loop "scrolls" through rows whose `enumerate` column is still empty and updates it until the counter variable `i` reaches the limit (`a`, `b` or `c`). Row to be updated is determined by the `ROWID` which is unique within the table. Yes, that's just a stupid copy/paste, but is simple and actually does the job.

Sample table (didn't feel like typing that much, so - only 14 rows here):

```
SQL> select * from test;

COUNT  ENUMERATE
----- ----------
AUS
MEX
USA
CHINA
AUS
MEX
USA
CHINA
AUS
MEX
USA
CHINA
AUS
MEX

14 rows selected.

SQL>
```

Code: variables are adjusted to those several sample rows:

```
SQL> declare
  2    a number := 3;
  3    b number := 4;
  4    c number := 2;
  5    i number;
  6  begin
  7    -- looping for A
  8    i := 1;
  9    for cur_r in (select country, rowid rid
 10                  from test
 11                  where enumerate is null
 12                 )
 13    loop
 14      update test set
 15        enumerate = i
 16        where rowid = cur_r.rid;
 17
 18      i := i + 1;
 19      exit when i > a;
 20    end loop;
 21
 22    -- looping for B
 23    i := 1;
 24    for cur_r in (select country, rowid rid
 25                  from test
 26                  where enumerate is null
 27                 )
 28    loop
 29      update test set
 30        enumerate = i
 31        where rowid = cur_r.rid;
 32
 33      i := i + 1;
 34      exit when i > b;
 35    end loop;
 36
 37    -- looping for C
 38    i := 1;
 39    for cur_r in (select country, rowid rid
 40                  from test
 41                  where enumerate is null
 42                 )
 43    loop
 44      update test set
 45        enumerate = i
 46        where rowid = cur_r.rid;
 47
 48      i := i + 1;
 49      exit when i > c;
 50    end loop;
 51  end;
 52  /

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.
```

Result:

```
SQL> select * from test;

COUNT  ENUMERATE
----- ----------
AUS            1    -- the first 3 rows represent 
MEX            2    -- variable A
USA            3    -- whose value is 3
CHINA          1       -- the next 4 rows
AUS            2       -- belong to 
MEX            3       -- variable B
USA            4       -- whose value is 4
CHINA          1    -- the last 2 rows
AUS            2    -- belong to variable C, set to 2
MEX
USA
CHINA
AUS
MEX

14 rows selected.

SQL>
```

Comment: No, it is not. SQL is a *language*. Database is something different.

Comment: The database that I´m using is SQL. the main reason to enumerate the rows is because I need to make an analysis on excel using the data from SQL using 3 or more variables depending on the necessities for the input

Comment: Once again, no. Databases are e.g. MySQL, PostgreSQL, MariaDB, Oracle, MS SQL Server. "SQL" is acronym for "structured query language" - **language**, and we use it to access data stored within the database. All database vendors more or less follow ANSI standards for SQL, but each of them has its own *flavor*, offering functions and features others either have, or do not have - and then it depends on the **database** whether you can (re)use code written for some other database, using that database's SQL.